# C# DataGridViev Textbox Validation

Tags: c#, validation, datagrid

I'm trying to validate any textbox in any DataGridView if it already contains `.`

I got this code which gives me `InvalidCastException`.

Any idea how to get around?

```
if (((DataGridTextBox)sender).Text.Contains(".") & e.KeyChar == '.')
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure sender is what you think it is? have you tried setting a breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your "sender" isn't DataGridTextBox type. You can check it with code below:

```
DataGridTextBox dataGridTextBox = sender as DataGridTextBox;
        if (dataGridTextBox != null)
        {
            //It's DataGridTextBox
        }
        else
        {
            //It isn't DataGridTextBox
        }
```

So, you should to know type of your "sender", to do validation.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with "EditingConrolShowing" event added for the DataGridView and folloing code:

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) //This is to allow nubers with one dot as decimal place only in all datagrids
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);

```
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
            }

    }

    private void Column1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) //This is to allow nubers with one dot as decimal place only in all datagrids
    {
        if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) & (Keys)e.KeyChar != Keys.Back & e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Contains(".") & e.KeyChar == '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```